# Conditional Testing with Cypress e2e

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I have a test case of my site with cypress. however the site, which is been built in vue.js has lets say 2 journeys. in one of them there is an button which I want to click. So, what I want to do is the following:

```js
if ('button exists') {
  cy.get(#"button-class").click()    //basically click the button
}
```

If the button isn't there, which can be true for the second journey then carry on, as no button will be there.

Whatever I have tried so far failed. All I want is a simple if statement in cypress.

Answer (score 4):

This became a lot easier with the release of [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) package

```js
cy.get(#"button-class")
  .if()
  .click()
```

---

#### Update for Cypress v12

Recent internal changes in Cypress have made this package stop working.

Please see this issue [Can we please overwrite query commands #25078](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25078) and register your "vote" if you like the package and wish it were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent element of the button, which should be displayed everytime and query for your button inside its `then()` callback

```js
cy.get('css of always displayed parent').then($parent => {
    if ($parent.find('#button-class').length) {
        cy.wrap($parent).find('#button-class').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: i have no parent element. there are 2 -3 different div basically that they are rendered depending on the insurrer we choose. this choice is asyc. meaning that one time might be choosing insurer A and next time B or C. now on the next page not all the insurers have this button! thats why i need conditial rendering? inst anything simple? i did:
if (cy.get(#button-class){
// code here
}

but cy.get(#button-class) isnt evaluating to true or false :( and thats what i need. something to tell me if the button is there or not! :(

Comment: The way you want to do it is unfortunately not compatible with how cypress commands are built. Each cypress command return a promise so `cy.get()` will never return true or false.
Maybe you can try to replace `'css of always displayed parent'` by `'body'`